# How can it be Distuingsed that below code follows MVVM or Not?

Tags: android, mvvm, workflow

I am not able to understand What actually is the MVVM??

Is it the only approach to  make out the Code Cleaner or Something like Design pattern, I am not Able to Understand what actually is the MVVM.

I have worked out with a simple tutorial as i Did always with using DataBinding .How can it be Distinguished that it has not followed the MVVM ??

I got Simple Question here, hoping that i will get Clear Answer with example.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        User user = new User("Android", "ios", "Blackberry");
        activityMainBinding.setVariable(user);



    }
}
```

**modal class**

```
public class Client {
    String name;


public Client(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

**layout**

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="variable"
        type="com.example.user_pc.databinding.User" />

</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:text="@{variable.firstName}"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/middleName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:text="@{variable.middleName}" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:text="@{variable.lastName}" />


</LinearLayout>
```

> This seems to be Simpler Question but i am struggling to understand
>   MVVM and it's Work flow.All are making Different Directory for the model,view and viewmodel ,is it only of making direcotry different or what ? i got no clear concept.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not about packages. An architecture is essential for abstraction. 
MVVM or MVP (both are not the same) helps in abstraction of your business layer and View layer.

I won't elaborate over here, you can read blogs for that.

MVVM is most useful when you use observables, like in databinding, LiveData or RX observables. You can just change the value in your viewModel, and the changes will be reflected in the UI. You don't have to use 
*textView.setText()* again and again.

Ok, so let's break down(let's keep things simple)

**View** consists of activity, fragments, etc.

The **ViewModel** is responsible for wrapping the model and preparing observable data needed by the view. It also provides hooks for the view to pass events to the model. The ViewModel is not tied to the view however. It contains an interface ViewModel and the different ViewModels associated with different activities. Here is a link to the android [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html)

The **model** holds the data and state of the app.

You can find these descriptions everywhere. The most important part is why should we use these architectures?

Say for example you have an app, where you have to calculate the sum of values provided in two text fields, **textA** and **textB** into another text field **textC**

You need a Model class **Sum** to store the data and display or save it.

```
public class Sum{
 public int num1,num2,sum;// make these observable.
}
```

Let's assume this a tough problem, and you would love to concentrate just on your business logic at first, and after successfully implementing the logic, you would move to changing your views.

So, you write your ViewModel class

```
public class SumViewModel extends ViewModel{
 // implement other required methods and variables, if possible LiveData.
// either you can use Databinding Observable, and share the same Sum object in
// View and ViewModel or you can use LiveData as shown in the link.
Sum s; 
 public void onSumPressed(int a, int b){
s.num1 = a;
s.num2 = b;
s.sum = a+b;
}
public void clearPressed(){
s.num1=0;
s.num2=0;
s.sum=0;
}
}
```

So, You have successfully implemented the business logic. Phew! Now, it's time you can concentrate on your views

```
public class SumActivity extends AppcompatActivity{
  Sum s;// as discussed, you can make this observable.
private SumViewModel model;
private ActivitySumBinding binding;
onCreate(){
...
 model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SumViewModel.class);
int a = Integer.parseInt(binding.text1.getText().toString());
int b = Integer.parseInt(binding.text2.getText().toString());
binding.sumBtn.setOnclickListener(v-> model.onSumPressed(a,b));
//Now, since the object s is being obseverd, data will be changed in the view accordingly.
...
}

}
```

The program is for demo only.

I want you to notice the main agenda. We break our goals and concentrate on one at a time. We first implement our business logic, and then move on to make the appropriate view changes. Moreover adjusting new requirements are pretty easy, since you just have to keep on adding methods.

Another great things about MVVM is that our View Model is now extremely easy to unit test.

Comment: i got a little clarification in here ,i will dig in full.is MVVM better than MVP?